# How do I add a Battle.Net Friend after a game of StarCraft 2 without using the score summary screen?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

Sometimes when I finish a multi-player game I am not taken to the score summary screen, but am instead dropped on the My Profile screen. Unfortunately, a few times this has resulted in me being unable to add a new found friend to my list of Battle.Net contacts.

Is there a mechanism without knowing a users Gamer ID to add that user to your friends list? If I'm not taken directly to the score screen is there a way to get there before my next match so I can add a user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about going to your "Match history" and selecting the game you just played? It should take you to the "score-summary" and there you should also be able to add the player as a friend.

Answer (score 3):

1. Keep your friend list short, battlenet will slow down seriously if it's long.
2. You can go to match history on your profile and find the previous score screens from there.
3. If you know the user's real-id or nick+number, you can manually add them by clicking "add friend" on the friend list.
4. In Battle.Net forums, you can click the arrow next to the user's name to find out their number.

Comment: why is it getting slower when you have more friends?

Comment: It's been 4 years, there are good odds things changed since then. Beside that, it was a observation, i can describe it but not explain it. I /can/ guess it was because it had to load the entire list before it could continue.